# Работа с базами данных на Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, база-данных, visual-studio

Пытаюсь найти хоть какое-то обучение работы с базами данных.
Спрашиваю у людей и максимум, что я слышу, так это название каких-то способов типа ADO, OBDC и т.д.
А где хоть какой-нибудь туториал на русском языке? Никто не знает. Никто. Как вы учили то без туториалов?

Comment: Изучите работы с запросами SQL. Как сделаете - жизнь станет гораздо проще, т.к. тот же [ADO][1] их [использует][2]. А потом прикрутить какой-нибудь опенсурсный [firebird][3] вообще проблемой не будет.

 [1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx
 [2]:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998
 [3]:http://www.firebirdsql.org/

Comment: Основы SQL я знаю. Это никак мне не помогает понять как работать с бд через C++, а не через СУБД.

Comment: Грубо говоря - открываете базу данных через библиотеку, формируете запрос и через специальную ф-цию этой самой библиотеки его получаете. Далее уже средствами языка разбираетесь с тем, что получили. Посмотрите те же примеры использования firebird.

Comment: Вначале это довольно объёмный математический аппарат. Потом уже идёт имплементация.

Comment: У меня примерно та же проблема, что и у вас. Вижу, что тема старая. По прошествии столь большого времени вы научились работать с БД в С++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы бы хоть уточнили, с какой базой работать собираетесь и как. Есть такая штука Entity Framework позволяет работать с БД, как с набором классов (это если сильно утрировать), но для того, чтобы подключаться к БД нужен .NET провайдер к конкретной базе. Если к фреймворкам доверия нет, то вот пример на C# как это делать руками, на C++ должно быть аналогично, метод занимается записью данных в БД FireBird:

```
 public void MyExecuteNonQuery(string command, Dictionary<string, object> paramList)
    {
        FbConnection fb = new FbConnection(PMSys.Properties.Settings.Default.configurationString);
        fb.Open();
        FbTransaction fbt = fb.BeginTransaction();
        FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(command, fb);
        cmd = ParamIterator<string, object>(cmd, paramList);
        cmd.Transaction = fbt;
        try
        {
            int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            fbt.Commit(); //если вставка  прошла успешно - комитим транзакцию
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            fb.Close();
        }
    }
```

Что-то конкретное, те же туториалы можно подсказать, когда вы определитесь, с какой БД конкретно будете работать. В целом, работа с БД везде происходит по одной схеме создали соединение → открыли его → создали транзакцию → создали команду -> отправили команду → если все прошло успешно, Commit транзакции → закрыли соединение

Comment: Сначала по проще хотел бы работать с MS Access или другой простой БД. Да пусть даже будет что-то по сложнее, например, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle и т.д., просто я даже не нашел как работать с такими БД.
Бд не важно, хотя хотелось бы попроще.
Мне все равно как работать. Пусть будет фреймворк, но главное требование: C++. Не C++/CLI, не C#, не что-то еще.
Я не знаю, что такое .NET провайдер. Пусть будет .NET провайдер к БД, главное С++

Посмотрел Entity Framework в вики. Понял, что Entity Framework это .NET, а в .NET нет С++.

Comment: что значит в .NET нет С++ ? под .NET Вы можете писать хоть на Delphi, а про С++ я вообще молчу....

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_.NET-языков
И Дельфи там есть.

Comment: Да вообще что такое дотнет язык? Язык - это сущность абсолютно независимая от платформы, каковой дотнет и является. Если я сделаю компилятор для абстрактного языка в промежуточный код il дотнета, то станет ли этот язык дотнетовским???

Comment: Почему вы все только размышляете и размышляете? Почему никто не может просто дать ссылку на какое-нибудь обучение? Все знают, но никто не знает...

Comment: Вы не нервничайте=) если вам нужна работа с БД (неважно какой) без использования .NET, (хотя не понимаю, если вы все равно используете Visual Studio, зачем отказываться от .NET?), то примеры можно посмотреть по ссылке ниже, раздел "Примеры на С++ и VB для Firebird и Interbase". Для других БД принцип будет тот же самый: качаете нужный (например OLE DB для FireBird) провайдер и далее по схеме выше.
http://www.ibprovider.com/rus/documentation/examples.html
Вот тут можно почитать про ODBC и OLE DB провайдеры:
http://www.ibprovider.com/rus/documentation/firebird_interbase_odbc_drivers.html

Comment: Я понял, что надо просто залезть в документацию какой-нибудь бд(которая интересна) и там посмотреть. Правда придется повозиться с англ. документацией.
Почему не использую .NET? Потому что он не поддерживает C++, если судить по вики.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если уж вам в С++ так хочется, возможно вам понравится QT)))
Ну а в Visual Studio удобнее с базами работать используя [ADO.NET](http://ADO.NET).
И ваше приложение написанное на с++/CLI будет работать под платформу .NET

Comment: Хочу остаться на VS, тем более, что я учу DirectX.
C++/CLI меня тоже не очень интересует.

Answer (score 2):

Ссылку по данной теме в сети сами найдете, тот-же MSDN. Позволю дать Вам совет: очень неудобно, как по мне, писать приложение баз данных в VC++. Гораздо проще, быстрее, реализовать такую задачу в Borland Builder C++.